# routeProvider to trigger again for the same route

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I have a controller that is triggered upon changing the route say "#/a".

Now I want to trigger controller again for the same route. Since the route hasn't been changed it doesn't trigger.

Now I'm unsetting the route and setting it to trigger. Is there any other way?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Mostly out of curiosity: why do you want to create the controller again? That seems like an odd thing to do to me.

Comment: because the previous controller is dead.

Comment: What does "dead" mean? Usually if you want the controller to continue handling events you would add event handlers. The only sort of situation I can think of where you'd just want to rerun a controller is if you wanted to do something like cancel out of a form view and reset it to its pristine condition.

Comment: "dead" mean it has ended life cycle and the div (say like pop) is removed. Apologies if the my terminology is confusing.

Comment: maybe `$route.reload()` will do what you need? I'm not sure I undestand your problem very well, but reloading the current route seems like a good fit to what you want